# Deletion of list members by rules

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {{"a","b","c","d","e","f"}, {"a","b","g","d","p","f"}, {"i","j","k","l","m","f"}, {"a","b","xx","d","xx","f"}}
```

Looking only at list members that have identical values at the first, second, fourth and sixth positions, I would like to delete those list members whose third and fifth positions are "xx", which gives:

```
res = {{"a","b","c","d","e","f"}, {"a","b","g","d","p","f"}, {"i","j","k","l","m","f"}}
```

A previous suggestion was:

```
DeleteDuplicatesBy[MapAt["xx" &, {{3}, {5}}]]@lis
```

which gives:

```
badRes = {{"a","b","c","d","e","f"}, {"i","j","k","l","m","f"}}
```

which omits one desired element.

Comment: What should the response be to `lis = {{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "g", "d", "p", 
   "f"}, {"i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "f"}, {"a", "b", "xx", "d", "xx", 
   "f"}, {"i", "j", "xx", "l", "xx", "f"}
  , {"a", "b", "xx", "d", "p", "f"}
  }` ?

Comment: Try: `lis /. {_, _, x_, _, x_, _} -> Nothing`

Comment: @syed just saw your comment, fortunately, if there is "xx" at position three, there will always be an "xx" at position five in this data set.

Comment: @Daniel Huber thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rep[a_] /; a[[3]] == "xx" && a[[5]] == "xx" := Nothing
rep[a_] := a

rep /@ lis
```

{{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "g", "d", "p", "f"}, {"i","j", "k", "l", "m", "f"}}

Slower Alternatives:

```
SequenceReplace[lis, {{_, _, "xx", _, "xx", _} ..} :> Nothing]
```

{{"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"}, {"a", "b", "g", "d", "p", "f"}, {"i",
"j", "k", "l", "m", "f"}}

and, giving the same result,

```
SubsetReplace[lis, {{_, _, "xx", _, "xx", _} ..} :> Nothing]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `Select`:

```
Select[lis, Not[#[[3]] == "xx" && #[[5]] == "xx"] &] === res

(*True*)
```

Also, using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[lis, {__, "xx", _, "xx", __}] === res

(*True*)
```